# Groovy: Create a new node

Tags: xml, groovy

I am building the parent xml by reading it from a request xml Here is the code:

```
def createXML(requestXML)
{
  def formXML = new XmlSlurper().parseText(requestXML)
  def formMap = [:]
  formXML.children.each {
   formMap[it.name()] = it
  }
  buildComponentXML(formMap)

}

def buildComponentXML(formMap)
{
  def compXML = formMap['componentName']
  def anotherNode = new Node (compXML, 'AnotherNode',1234555)
  println XmlUtil.serialize(compXML)
}
```

**Exception**

```
Could not find matching constructor for: groovy.util.Node(groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you have some example for `requestXML`?  Not sure that sticking the nodes into a Map will gain you anything over just using the result from `parseText`...  What output are you expecting?

Comment: I am adding a thin client to a legacy application. This means translating thin client's flat request xml to legacy application's layered request xml. Requet XML I have, has some business data. Will try to post something with similar structure.

Comment: C'mmon guys. Why has it been downvoted? Just google `add a new node using Groovy` and go through first 5 pages. You will know my research effort.

Comment: The downvote is a bit harsh imho. Don't let it get you down Himanshu...  Haters gonna hate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say, but what I *think* you want is:

```
def buildComponentXML( formMap ) {
  def compXML = formMap['componentName']
  compXML.appendNode { AnotherNode( 1234555 ) }
  println XmlUtil.serialize(compXML)
}
```

But then, that's the same as:

```
def createXML( requestXML ) {
  def formXML = new XmlSlurper().parseText(requestXML)
  buildComponentXML(formXML)
}

def buildComponentXML( formXML ) {
  formXML.'componentName'.appendNode { AnotherNode( 1234555 ) }
  println XmlUtil.serialize(formXML)
}
```

As sticking things into a map is kinda duplicating the effort of XmlSlurper (assuming I have the correct end of the stick wrt what you're trying to do)

Comment: Oh Thanks a lot for the genius answer. Its my third day with Groovy.

Comment: No worries, there's never a silly question! Fingers crossed this works  (and isn't a silly answer) ;-)